# Is it possible to view data as it is being imported in Teradata?

Tags: import, teradata

I'm trying to import data from a txt file and keep getting a 'Wrong number of data values in row xxx' error. Looking at the text file, everything looks fine but I can't tell what/how Teradata is interpreting it.

So is there a way to view or preview the data from Teradata's perspective? I tried running a SELECT statement, but since the import doesn't finish, nothing is even imported. Which brings me to my next question, is there a way to limit an external-file import to a certain # of rows? Like import just the first 50 rows from the text file?

Comment: Which tool do you use for import? One of the Teradata supplied load tools like BTEQ/FastLoad/MLoad/TPT? Is this a comma delimited text file?

Comment: I honestly haven't been able to figure out what tool I'm using, but I've been just using the default one under File - Import Data. While searching for help, I found [this link](http://forums.teradata.com/forum/tools/difference-between-load-export-utilities) and BTEQ seems to fit the description of what I'm using, but I'm not 100% sure. Even for importing a few thousand rows, it's very slow. I can see TD processing 1 row at a time

Comment: Seems you're not using any of those utilities :-)  Do you run a **INSERT ... VALUES(?,?,?)** from within SQL Assistant? Goto Tools-Options-Import and increase the maximum bath size to at least 100 and check "Silently discard rows that cause constraint violations". This might load at least some rows. Can you show a input row from that file?

Comment: Yep, I'm using INSERT ... VALUES(?,?,?) from within SQL Assistant. I've already increased the batch size to 1000 yet it still has been running about the same speed as before. When I run the import, it will get to about row #900 and then give the error I mentioned before. After that error, when I run a select query, I see nothing but the table grain/definition

Comment: If the table is empty you probably load your table within a single transaction, which means your session is in ANSI mode. Try changing the session mode from ANSI or ystem Default to Teradata, in ODBC it's in the Options, in .NET on the Advanced tab. How many rows are you trying to load? Maybe you should switch to a 'real' load tool :-)

Comment: What text editor are you using to view the file which you are attempting to import?

Comment: dnoeth: how exactly do I open up ODBC? Is it another program/application? And I would use a 'real' load tool, but we're getting rid of the only one we had since it was expensive.

Comment: Rob: I'm just using Notepad. Does this make a big difference as to which text editor I use?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you obtain a copy of [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/), both of which are free to download, to view the text file. This will allow you to open the text file and identify what in the records is causing you trouble loading the file. You will be able to display non-printable characters and use advanced search techniques to traverse the files looking for problems with the data.

It is possible there is an embedded carriage return, line feed, or other non-printable character that is being interpreted during the import and generating this error.